# Bootstrap - What would be the best way to have a card over a jumbotron?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I'm working on a project and I would like to have the card be overlaying the jumbotron. (see picture) This card will be inside the body of website though. This is a pretty generic question, but I'm pretty confused on how to accomplish such a task in bootstrap.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/r0ny4dh6/6/
Maybe this will help you

to fix the sidebar while scrolling, I recommend **PrettyScroll** plugin:

JS:

```
new PrettyScroll('.js-sidebar', {
    breakpoint: 575, // stop running the js when the window size is smaller than 575px
    offsetTop: 200, // space between the sticky element and the top of the window
    offsetBottom: 20, // space between the sticky element and the bottom of the window
});
```

CSS

```
aside .box {
   position: relative;
}
aside .card {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  transform: translateY(-200px);
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.demo {
  padding: 100px;
}
.jumbotron {
  padding-bottom: 200px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="demo">
  <div class="container">
    <header>
      <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1 class="display-4">Hello, world!</h1>
        <p class="lead">This is a simple hero unit, a simple jumbotron-style component for calling extra attention to featured content or information.</p>
        <hr class="my-4">
        <p>It uses utility classes for typography and spacing to space content out within the larger container.</p>
      </div>
    </header>
    <div class="row">
      <aside class="col col-6">
        <div class="box">
          <div class="card js-sidebar">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="https://picsum.photos/600/200" alt="Card image cap">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </aside>
      <main class="col">
        a lot of text
      </main>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/pretty-scroll@1.1.0/js/pretty-scroll.js"></script>
```